# How to use TryCatch Statement in ToDictionary C#?

Tags: c#, linq, exception, try-catch

I have a dictionary of asyncronous call . The problem is sometimes these asyncronous call will throw an exception but I am not entirely sure how to handle them . The GetUserLicenseTypes returns a list so if I do get an exception I still want to return an empty list.

```
var tasks = allCompanyUsers.ToDictionary(
                u => u.Id,
                u => _subscriptionService.GetUserSubscription(companyId, u.Id));

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Values);

            var licenseListByUserId = tasks.ToDictionary(
                kvp => kvp.Key,
                kvp => kvp.Value.Result);
```

The code below doesn't work but I wanted to do something like this

```
var tasks = allCompanyUsers.ToDictionary(
                u => u.Id,
                u => {
try{
     return _subscriptionService.GetUserSubscription(companyId, u.Id);
}catch{
     return new List<string>();
}
});

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Values);

            var licenseListByUserId = tasks.ToDictionary(
                kvp => kvp.Key,
                kvp => kvp.Value.Result);
```

Note : I have gotten feedback that I should just avoid exception all together but at the moment it is hard to do considering that the GetUserSubscription function is already used in many location so the typical convention our application use is a trycatch statement to handle these thrown error.

Comment: Your try-catch code doesn't work because the task(s) returned by the `GetUserSubscription()` method aren't awaited within the scope of the `try` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetSubscriptions(Guid userId)
{
    try { return await _subscriptionService.GetUserSubscription(companyId, userId); }
    catch { return new List<string>(); }
}

var idsWithSubscriptions = await Task.WhenAll(allCompanyUsers
    .Select(async u => (
        u.Id,
        Subscription: await GetSubscriptions(u.Id))));

var licenseListByUserId = idsWithSubscriptions.ToDictionary(
    iws => iws.Id,
    iws => iws.Subscription);
```

Because the `Task` returned from `GetUserSubscription` is awaited, it will unwrap and throw any `Exception`, meaning the value in the `catch` block will be returned.

Comment: Hi Johnathan, excuse my lack of c# knowledge but is there a method to make these request parallel . If I understand the code correctly it is waiting for each request before it moves to the next one. The example code I provided works except it doesn't know how to handle exception error. Perhaps I am contraining my code to much to fit the trycatch is there an alternative?

Comment: The example above is still parallel. The `Select` returns a set of incomplete `Tasks`, assuming `GetUserSubscription` is truly asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as the type of the values of your dictionary is `Task<List<string>>`, but in your catch block you return a `List<string>`. If you return a task, it should work:

```
var tasks = allCompanyUsers.ToDictionary(
u => u.Id,
u =>
{
   try
   {
        return _subscriptionService.GetUserSubscription(companyId, u.Id);
   }
   catch
   {
        return Task.FromResult(new List<string>());
   }
});
```

Comment: `GetUserSubscription` returns a `Task`, which will contain any exception, so no exception will be thrown inside the `try` block.